# LND doesnt create macaroons or directories

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, macaroon

I installed lnd and got to the point of creating a wallet with "lncli create" but I get an error "unable to read macaroon path" and gives the path of where the macaroon should be. I believe when you start lnd for the first time it creates these macaroons along with some other files and folders but mine only created

tls.cert
tls.key
logs/bitcoin/mainnet/lnd.log
data/graph/mainnet/channel.db

And no macaroons. Does anyone know why it would create only some of the files and folders?? Stumped!

Running on Ubuntu 20

Comment: So I installed v0.11.0-beta and it fixed the problem. There are definite bugs in the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of lnd is this? I had the same problem on git master, it vanished when I changed it to 0.11.0-beta. Seems to be a new bug. I already passed it on to a dev, but you might want to open a formal issue as well.